# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

The Line Try is Showing Red and :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
> Index 2 out of bounds for length 2    at
> skipcounting.Skipcounting.main(MyJava.java:11)

```java
package skipcounting;

public class Skipcounting {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      int[][] numbers = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {10, 20, 30, 40, 50}};
      for (int i = 0; i < numbers[1].length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numbers[1].length; j++) {
          System.out.println("numbers[" + i + "][" + j + "]=" + numbers[i][j]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Error Shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVpS8.png)

Comment: `z< numbers[1].length` in outer loop should be `z< numbers.length`. `z< numbers.length` gives you number of rows while `z< numbers[1].length` gives you number of columns. You have 2 rows 5 col. But in code you are iterating over 5 rows and 5 col. And since you only have 2 rows. You get arrayoutofboundexception

Comment: Together with the output : The Output Should be 
numbers[0][0]=1
numbers[0][1]=2
numbers[0][2]=3
numbers[0][3]=4
numbers[0][4]=5
numbers[1][0]=10
numbers[1][1]=20
numbers[1][2]=30
numbers[1][3]=40
numbers[1][4]=50

Comment: and also the line try{ shows red

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to ask. Were you able to understand my comment?

Comment: With a **try** there should be a **catch**. `Try` sets the error trap and `catch` snags the error so that you can eat it (process it). :D

Comment: Ow I  get it HAHA Thank You !

Comment: @DevilsHnd OP doesn't need try catch just to iterate over a 2D array. OP seems to be stuck in XY problem.

Comment: Now...was `what do I need?` the question? I think it's more important for the OP to know that catch should be with a Try.

Comment: @DevilsHnd No! That is not what the try catch is for. What Op need is a class on data structures and for loops. Putting try catch in code when it can be easily avoided is horrible advice.

Comment: Who is giving advise? I didn't provide advice...I provided a fact!

Comment: @DevilsHnd You by giving him a misleading answer. OP doesn't need try catch in this case at all. OP thought that the issue should be fixed using try catch which is horrible coding.

Comment: Sorry, I am Just new in Java Programming and i trying to advance lesson in java.

Comment: @Goion one day you'll learn

Comment: @Chemistry Major Well because you are new. I think it is wrong to teach you something incorrect. Everyone is a beginner at one point. We all learn by making mistakes. Check the answer by Amit Chaudhary

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is the way you are getting the number of rows and column in your 2D array.

1. `int[][]numbers ={{1,2,3,4,5},{10,20,30,40,50}}` - meaning that there are 2 rows and and for each row there are 5 columns.
2. `int[][]numbers ={{1,2,3,4,5},{10,20,30,40,50,60,70}}` - If you look at this, there are 2 rows but for 1st row there are 5 columns and for 2nd row there are 7 columns

if you want to get the number of rows use this - `numbers.length`

if you want to get number of columns in a row use this - `numbers[row_index].length`

So in your question the correct code world be-

```
for (int i=0; i< numbers.length; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<numbers[i].length; j++){
                System.out.println("numbers["+i+"]["+j+"]="+ numbers[i][j]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Let me know.

```
public class Skipcounting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][]numbers ={{1,2,3,4,5},{5,10,15,20,25}};
        for (int z = 0; z < 2; z++){ // Fixed from "z<numbers[1].length to "z<2".
            for (int o = 0; o < 5; o++){ //Fixed from "z++" to "o++".
                System.out.println("numbers["+z+"]["+o+"]="+ numbers[z][o]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should tell why OP code wasn't working. This code may fix the bug but not really address the problem.

Comment: @Chemistry Major Your code wasn't working because of two main reasons:

1) In your second for-loop you had "z++" instead of "o++", thus, you were incrementing z twice, leading to array index bound issues.
2) Your first for-loop was bound to "z<numbers.length[1]", however, this is equal to 5. Thus, you were trying to access an array that is at an index larger than 1 (e.g. numbers[3]) which was the second reason to your array index bound issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Put the comment in your answer as well.

Comment: Remove the try-catch block. It is not necessary. BTW you schould not catch the base class exception.